# Run macro for selected layers separately

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I wonder if there's a way to run photoshop macro for few selected layers SEPARATELY.

For example, I have macro for prepare images to save for web:
1. duplicate selected layer to new document
2. trim transparent pixels

If I select 2 layers and run this macro - photoshop duplicating these 2 layers to one new document. I want to duplicate these 2 layers to 2 new document by one click.

Greets. ;)

Comment: Hmm is the trim in step 2 occurring on the original or on the new document? Could you upload a screenshot showing the Action in question Expanded?

Comment: Yep, step2 occurs in second step, in new document. (i have polish version of PS so screenshot is nonsense)

Comment: It's only doable with a script.